# Recursion in Integration by Parts

Tags: integration-by-parts

I'm trying to integrate by parts, but I keep getting recursive answers.

$I=\int_0^\pi f(x)cos(x)dx$ 
where $f''(x)=3f(x)$, $f'(0)=-5$, and $f'(\pi)=4$

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you find $f$ explicitly as some exponential function?

Comment: @Ian not that I am aware of

Comment: After second IBP, you will have same integral your looking for in the RHS of equation. Then take it to LHS, in which you will find $a•I$. Then divide both sides by $a$, here you got $I$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion will eventually be in terms of itself, which means you can solve for $I$. So:
\begin{align*}
I = \int_0^\pi f(x)\cos x\,dx &= f(x) \sin x\, \bigg|_0^\pi - \int_0^\pi f'(x)\sin x\,dx \\
&= 0 - \bigg( f'(x)(-\cos x)\, \bigg|_0^\pi - \int_0^\pi f''(x)(-\cos x)\,dx \bigg) \\
&= f'(\pi)\cos \pi - f'(0)\cos 0 - \int_0^\pi 3f(x)\cos x\,dx \bigg) \\
&= (-5)(-1) - 4(0) - 3I.
\end{align*}
Therefore $4I=1$, or $I=\frac14$.